# Couldn't find [model] with ID rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
def album_list
    @albums = Album.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM albums;')

end
def alt_album_list
    @albums = Album.find(:all)
    render(:action => 'album_list')

end
def show_album
    @album = Album.find(:first)

end
def show
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    render(:action => 'show_album')

end
def new 
    @album = Album.new
end
```

This is my rout :

```
MusicLibrary::Application.routes.draw do
resources :albums
resources :public
get "public/album_list"
get "public/alt_album_list"
get "public/one_album_list"
get "public/show_album"
get 'public/show'
get 'public/create'
get 'public/new'
get 'public/edit'
```

MODEL :

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Interesting </title>
</head>
<body> 
<%= form_for(@album) do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.label :artist %>
<%= f.text_field :artist %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.label :genre %>
<%= f.text_field :genre %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.label :release_date %>
<%= f.datetime_select :release_date %>
</p>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

</body>

</html>
```

I have an error LIKE : `Couldn't find [model] with ID rails 4`
I know this can be very simple`controller`, `model`, and view, but it does not work because of that error. I did not copy the whole content of `Controller` because it was useless. The rest of code looks like good and work fine, but ...

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace and error message?

Comment: You need to provide code that's associated with the error you're getting. Since it appears that the `show` is failing (the only `find` that is passing an ID), you need to involve the code that generates the URL used to "get" the "show" page.

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PublicController#show
Couldn't find Album with id=show

Extracted source (around line #16):
14
15
16
17
18
19
          
 end
 def show
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  render(:action => 'show_album')
  
 end

Rails.root: /home/ostadfreee/rails_projects/music_library

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/public_controller.rb:16:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"show"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None    THANKS A LOT

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get a notice about your comment, since you didn't start it with `@Peter Alfvin`, and just saw it now. That confirms what I suspected (that the error is within the controller `show` method), but what I asked you to share was the code that was generating the URL that got you to the `show` controller. Please also share the output of `rake routes`.  My guess is that you're somehow generating a URL which has `album/id` in it rather than (say) `album/24`.

Comment: Also, please put all the code in your question so that it can be formatted.

Comment: @Peter Alfvin   I decided not to follow that tutorial anymore, though I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Since you're new to StackOverflow, allow me to say that you might want to upvote either or both of the answers you received if they were useful to you in any way (e.g. in increasing your understanding of Rails).

Comment: If you want to follow an updated tutorial, I think this should be a very good starting point: http://www.railstutorial.org/book

Answer (score 0):

This could be a longshot since you haven't posted the complete info. But as you mentioned you're using Rails 4, it seems you have some outdated syntax going on.

```
def album_list
  @albums = Album.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM albums;')
end

def alt_album_list
  @albums = Album.all
  render :album_list
end

def show_album
  @album = Album.first
end
```

Comment: Yeah, also I don't get why you need the `find_by_sql` method since you're only pulling all records.

Comment: I am following an old tutorial and I think this might be a reason which time to time I can get an odd error like above. If you could fix   it, I would appreciate.

Comment: Didn't I just fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your error:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PublicController#show Couldn't find Album with id=show 
Means that you're not passing in an id, which probably means you have some sort of collision probably by hand that is being caused by your duplication of routes.

resources automatically gives you a show route with an id, however the manual one you put in does not and will allow an id unless you make it:
get "public/:id/show"

I would guess where every you're clicking your show link, or redirect link you're somehow using the wrong route.

I would remove your unnecessary get routes and do it like this though:

```
resources :public do
  get "album_list", :on => collection
  get "alt_album_list", :on => collection
  get "one_album_list", :on => collection
  get "show_album", :on => collection
end
```

I would also follow the other advice of using, all, instead of find(:all) and the rest suggested in the other post just to make your application cleaner and up to date.